# Connect IPv4-only devices to IPv6-only services and vice versa

Tags: networking, debian, android, ipv6, ipv4

I have mobile devices (Android), whose network providers do not support IPv6. My fiber network provider (for internet connection at home) uses only IPv6 with Dual Stack lite, so they are only reachable via IPv6. I have a couple services running at home (HTTP/HTTPS/Email-Server via POP3&SMTP/and soon applications developed by myself) (on Raspbian/Debian) which i need to be able to connect to from every network (IPv4). I have a VPS (Debian 9) with full Dual Stack access with an option to rent an entire /64 IPv6-Subnet. How can i make my home services (IPv6 only) available to the entire web (using the static IPv4 and IPv6 address of the VPS) and also provide my Android devices with IPv6?